# How do I find and plot the intersection of these three surfaces?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematica-online

I know how to find the region of intersection of these cylinders using integration, but how would I plot that in mathematica? This is what I have

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + z^2 == 1, 
  y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: This is what I have so far]

Comment: The intersection of the three surfaces would be eight points. You could use Solve[] to find them

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100825/4999

Comment: How would I do that? by defining an InfinitePlane through the points on the cylinder?

Comment: Use Solve[] with the three equations

Answer (score 7):

You can use region functionality for this. Here is the intersection of the boundary of the cylinders:

```
reg = RegionIntersection[
    RegionBoundary @ Cylinder[{{0,0,-2},{0,0,2}}],
    RegionBoundary @ Cylinder[{{0,-2,0},{0,2,0}}],
    RegionBoundary @ Cylinder[{{-2,0,0},{2,0,0}}]
];
```

Here is a visualization of the points of intersection:

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[reg, MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}]
```

[image]

And the values of the intersection:

```
MeshPrimitives[mesh, 0]
```

> {Point[{0.707107, 0.707107, -0.707107}], 
>    Point[{-0.707107, -0.707107, 0.707107}], 
>    Point[{0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107}], 
>    Point[{-0.707107, -0.707107, -0.707107}], 
>    Point[{0.707107, -0.707107, 0.707107}], 
>    Point[{-0.707107, 0.707107, -0.707107}], 
>    Point[{-0.707107, 0.707107, 0.707107}], 
>    Point[{0.707107, -0.707107, -0.707107}]}

Visualization of the intersection of the solid cylinders (blue) and the intersection of the boundary of the cylinders (red):

```
reg2 = RegionIntersection[
    Cylinder[{{0,0,-1},{0,0,1}}],
    Cylinder[{{0,-1,0},{0,1,0}}],
    Cylinder[{{-1,0,0},{1,0,0}}]
];

Show[Region @ reg2, mesh]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can show the lines corresponding to intersection of pairs of three surfaces using the option `BoundaryStyle`. You can get the points where all three surfaces intersect using `NSolve` (as Michael suggested in comments) and use them with `Graphics3D` and put the two graphics together using `Show`:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z]
pnts = {x, y, z} /. NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + z^2 == 1, y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y, z}];

Show[ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + z^2 == 1, y^2 + z^2 == 1}, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> {Placed[SwatchLegend[ "Expressions"], Right], 
     Placed[LineLegend[{Orange, Purple, Cyan},
          {"intersection(1, 2)", "intersection(1, 3)", "intersection(2, 3)"}], Right], 
     Placed[PointLegend[{Red}, {"intersection(1, 2, 3)"}], Right]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[.4], 
  BoundaryStyle -> {{1, 2} -> Directive[Orange, Thick], 
    {1, 3} -> Directive[Purple, Thick], 
    {2, 3} -> Directive[Cyan, Thick]}], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[#, .2] & /@ pnts}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 < 1 &&
  x^2 + z^2 < 1 &&
  y^2 + z^2 < 1,
 {x, -1.2, 1.2},
 {y, -1.2, 1.2},
 {z, -1.2, 1.2},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]