# How to graph a solid common to multiple functions

Tags: graphics3d, regions, opencascade

I want to be able to graph the solid that is contained by two functions.  I am graphing x^2+z^2=400 and y^2+z^2=400 and this the code I used and the graph I got:

```
    Plot3D[{z = Sqrt[400 - x^2], z = Sqrt[400 - y^2], z = -Sqrt[400 - x^2],
    z = -Sqrt[400 - y^2]}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}]
```

[image]

I was wondering how I could graph the solid common to the cylinders aka the solid that the cylinders form.

Comment: For reference: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html

Comment: Related: [how-to-make-the-surface-of-a-3d-region-smooth](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211178/how-to-make-the-surface-of-a-3d-region-smooth)

Comment: Related: [intersecting-cylinders](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100825/intersecting-cylinders)

Answer (score 18):

Related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269363/72111

```
CSGRegion["Intersection", {Cylinder[{{0, -20, 0}, {0, 20, 0}}, 20], 
  Cylinder[{{-20, 0, 0}, {20, 0, 0}}, 20]}, BaseStyle -> Darker@Cyan]
```

[image: 3d rendering of union region]

**Edit**

Use `` OpenCascadeLink` ``  [as highlighted by @user21](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html):

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + z^2 <= 400, {x, y, z}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= 400, {x, y, z}];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[
   ToBoundaryMesh[reg1, {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> 1]];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[
   ToBoundaryMesh[reg2, {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, 
    MaxCellMeasure -> 1]];
bm = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[
    OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[shape1, shape2], 
    "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> .1}] // 
   BoundaryMeshRegion;
bm // Volume
RegionPlot3D[bm, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful stuff as usually. Just saw the edited version. Would it be possible to include a link to the original answer by user21? It's very good and I'd like to give an upvote to that as well :)

Comment: @bmf  We can  find another examples in user21's package `"OpenCascadeLink"`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html

Comment: oh cool. that's what you meant. thanks for the link :)

Comment: Add an answer here for completeness?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211178/how-to-make-the-surface-of-a-3d-region-smooth

Comment: @xzczd OK, Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[-Sqrt[400 - x^2] <= z <= 
    Sqrt[400 - x^2] && -Sqrt[400 - y^2] <= z <= Sqrt[400 - y^2], {x, 
   y, z}], MaxCellMeasure -> 1, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 50], Opacity[0.8], Orange]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To begin with, I think the following is more natural for the full plot

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + z^2 - 400, y^2 + z^2 - 400}, {x, -50, 
  50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Opacity[1], Opacity[1]}]
```

> [image: plot1]

And we can dissect different parts of it

```
one = RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + z^2 - 400 >= 0 && 
    y^2 + z^2 - 400 >= 0}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, 
  Mesh -> None]
```

> [image: plot2]

```
two = RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + z^2 - 400 >= 0 && 
    y^2 + z^2 - 400 <= 0}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

> [image: plot3]

```
three = RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + z^2 - 400 <= 0 && 
    y^2 + z^2 - 400 >= 0}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

> [image: plot4]

And finally

```
four = RegionPlot3D[{x^2 + z^2 - 400 <= 0 && 
    y^2 + z^2 - 400 <= 0}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {z, -50, 50}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

> [image: plot5]

You can use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine the different bits

```
Show[three, four]
```

> [image: show]

Answer (score 5):

Using CSG functionality introduced in 13.0

```
CSGRegion["Union",
 {Cylinder[{{-50, 0, 0}, {50, 0, 0}}, 20], 
  Cylinder[{{0, -50, 0}, {0, 50, 0}}, 20]}]
```

[image]

```
CSGRegion["Intersection",
 {Cylinder[{{-50, 0, 0}, {50, 0, 0}}, 20], 
  Cylinder[{{0, -50, 0}, {0, 50, 0}}, 20]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Plot[{-Cos[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> 0]

ParametricPlot3D[20 {{Cos[t], h, Sin[t]}, {h, Cos[t], Sin[t]}} // Evaluate,
  Element[{t, h}, reg]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

or

```
 ParametricPlot3D[
  20 {{Cos[t], u Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {u Cos[t], Cos[t], Sin[t]}}//Evaluate, 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```